# how to iterate through column values of pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe

[image]

I want to check each row for the address column and if it contains the substring "india"
then I need to add another column and say true
else false

and also i wanted to check the substring is present in the column value string if yes print yes else no.. this has to iterate for all the rows in dataframe.
like:

```
if "india" or "karnataka" is in sparkDF["address"]:
 print("yes")
else:
 print("no")
```

I'm getting the wrong results as it's checking for each character instead of the substring. How to achieve this?

[image]

How to achieve this?

I wasn't able to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise [contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.contains.html) or [like](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.like.html?highlight=like) for this

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
user,address
rishi,XYZ Bangalore Karnataka
kirthi,ABC Pune India
tushar,ASD Orissa India
"""
)

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter=',')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show()

+------+-----------------------+
|user  |address                |
+------+-----------------------+
|rishi |XYZ Bangalore Karnataka|
|kirthi|ABC Pune India         |
|tushar|ASD Orissa India       |
+------+-----------------------+
```

#### Contains

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('result',F.lower(F.col('address')).contains("india"))

sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+------+-----------------------+------+
|user  |address                |result|
+------+-----------------------+------+
|rishi |XYZ Bangalore Karnataka|false |
|kirthi|ABC Pune India         |true  |
|tushar|ASD Orissa India       |true  |
+------+-----------------------+------+
```

#### Like - Multiple Search Patterns

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('result',F.lower(F.col('address')).like("%india%") 
                             | F.lower(F.col('address')).like("%karnataka%") 
                            )

sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+------+-----------------------+------+
|user  |address                |result|
+------+-----------------------+------+
|rishi |XYZ Bangalore Karnataka|true  |
|kirthi|ABC Pune India         |true  |
|tushar|ASD Orissa India       |true  |
+------+-----------------------+------+
```

Comment: and also how to chreck if column address has "india" or "karnataka" and peforme certain operations if present for each row in sparkDF dataframe?

Comment: Vaebhav, can u help me with this too:    and also how to chreck if column address has "india" or "karnataka" and peforme certain operations if present for each row in sparkDF dataframe?

Comment: Updated the answer to demonstrate multiple patterns matches as well

Comment: i mean i wanted something like this like:   if "india" or "karnataka" in sparkDF['address']:
  print("yes")
else:
 print("no")


need to iterate this for all rows.

how to achieve this?

Comment: when i tried it , its giving wront results

Comment: i wanted something like this like: if "india" or "karnataka" in sparkDF['address']: print("yes") else: print("no")                                                              
 need to iterate this for all rows. how to achieve this?  im not getting proper results as its giving yes even if "i" is present. but i wanted to match whole substring for each row

Comment: @karthikkk - please update your question to include all details around your problem statement.

Comment: @samkart, i updated the question now. can you help me through this

Comment: @vaebhav, thats for your response, it helped me.   Can u help me through anothe rscenario as well:    if "india" or "karnataka" in sparkDF['address']: print("yes") else: print("no") need to iterate this for all rows. how to achieve this? im not getting proper results as its giving yes even if "i" is present. but i wanted to match whole substring for each row

Comment: @karthikkk -- using this answer's logic you can build a case when (`when().otherwise()`) statement that'll enable you to output your own string instead of boolean

Comment: im getting NameError: name 'F' is not defined error with above code, any idea?